# The onkey functions triggers late

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

```
from turtle import Screen
from snake import Snake
# from food import Food
# from score_board import Score_board
import time

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(width=600, height=600)
screen.bgcolor("black")
screen.title("My Snake Game")
screen.tracer(0)

snake = Snake()
# food = Food()
# score = Score_board()

screen.listen()
screen.onkey(snake.up, "Up")
screen.onkey(snake.down, "Down")
screen.onkey(snake.left, "Left")
screen.onkey(snake.right, "Right")


game_is_on = True

while game_is_on:
    screen.update()
    time.sleep(0.1)

    snake.move()

    # if snake.snake_body[0].distance(food) < 15:
    #     food.refresh()
    #     score.refresh()
    #     snake.extend()

    if snake.snake_body[0].xcor() < -280 or snake.snake_body[0].xcor() > 280 or snake.snake_body[0].ycor() < -280 or snake.snake_body[0].ycor() > 280:
        # score.game_over()
        game_is_on = False

    for segment in snake.snake_body[1:]:
        if snake.snake_body[0].distance(segment)<10:
            # score.game_over()
            game_is_on = False

screen.exitonclick()
```

```
from turtle import Turtle

STARTING_POSITIONS = [(0, 0), (-20, 0), (-40, 0)]


class Snake:

    def __init__(self):
        self.snake_body = []
        self.create_snake()

    def create_snake(self):
        for position in STARTING_POSITIONS:
            self.add_tail(position)

    def add_tail(self, position):
        new_part = Turtle("square")
        new_part.color("white")
        new_part.penup()
        new_part.goto(position)
        self.snake_body.append(new_part)

    def extend(self):
        self.add_tail(self.snake_body[-1].pos())

    def move(self):
        for part_num in range(len(self.snake_body) -1, 0, -1):
            new_x = self.snake_body[part_num - 1].xcor()
            new_y = self.snake_body[part_num - 1].ycor()
            self.snake_body[part_num].goto(new_x, new_y)
        self.snake_body[0].forward(20)


    def up(self):
        if self.snake_body[0].heading() != 270:
            self.snake_body[0].setheading(90)

    def down(self):
        if self.snake_body[0].heading() != 90:
            self.snake_body[0].setheading(270)

    def right(self):
        if self.snake_body[0].heading() != 180:
            self.snake_body[0].setheading(0)

    def left(self):
        if self.snake_body[0].heading() != 0:
            self.snake_body[0].setheading(180)
```

After I press a key, while loop loops around 3 times(snake.move() triggers 3 times) then onkey methods start to work

I tried playing with screen.update() putting it at the end of the loop or opening screen.tracer again to no solution.

Planned to debug but I still can not comprehend how onkey methods works without any loop, so I gave up

Comment: there are undefined variables in the example code.
the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)